# How to Connect to multiple Queue Managers and exchange data between them

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, mq

I am Trying to connect to multiple QueueManagers in IBM MQ Explorer using java. I am able to connect to single Queue Manager and send nd receive data from it but when i try to connect to a different Queue Manager and send data from first queue manager to second queue manager i get an error like :

```
o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'Q4' - trying to recover. 
Cause: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'Q4'.; 
nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').
```

This is my Code: https://github.com/PakaluPap1to/MQ_MultiQueue

I have added configuration for both the QueueManagers and their respective connection factories and JMS Operations.

I am very new to MQ and I am Not sure where i am going wrong, can anyone please help me to resolve this and guide me how can i achieve the required functionality ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks !

Comment: The error is descriptive.  The queue manger you connected to does not have a queue by that name.

Comment: Hi Josh, I have created a queue by that name in the IBM mq explorer.

Comment: Edit: I had a Q4 in my Queue Manager 4, I added a queue named Q4 in my queue manager 1 and now I am not getting any error(Thanks for that :) ). But my program is not sending data to the Q4 of the QM4 it is sending data to Q4 of QM1. Can you please guide as to what changes to make in the code to communicate data between two queue managers ?

Comment: You would need to connect to QM4.  Or are you asking how to get a queue on QM1 to send data to Q4 on QM4 outside of your program (this is not how your question reads)..

Comment: I have connected to QM4 in my program but it is not working as expected. No, I want to send data from QM1 to QM4 within my program itself. Can you please check my code and let me know if I have made any mistakes ?

Comment: Please update your question with your current problem. It seems that the problem you have described is no longer your problem? What issue is it that you are now experiencing? I looked at your code and the line to send to producer1 was commented out?

Comment: Hi Morag, I am still facing the same issue. I just added the queue Q4 in my QM1 so as to remove the error, but that is not how i want the code to perform. That line was comment was just to check if i get any errors(and i don't but it does not send message to q4 of QM4). When you uncomment that line from the listener it gives the same error as above.

Comment: I wanted to implement the functionality to communicate messages between Queue Managers. For eg: Q1 of QM1 should send and receive data from Q4 of QM4 within a single application.

Comment: So this tells me that you are not using the correct connection. You are trying to put a message to Q4 on QM4 but when you do it you are told you don't have a Q4. This tells me that you are actually trying to put a message to Q4 on QM1. You need to make sure you use the correct "hConn" in MQ parlance. You have two connections, one to QM1 and one to QM4, use the correct one on your put to Q4. btw - this would be easier to do if you put the relevant code in your question rather than a link to code where we have to navigate through the structure not knowing where to look.

Comment: Your client can talk to Q1 and talk to Q4 directly.  But it cannot talk to Q1 "through" Q4 unless you setup configuration (or any other combination).  We are talking channels, queues and remote queue aliases.  See the intercommunication documentation for MQ.

Comment: Hi Josh, Morag & Nic thanks for your valuable inputs. I have configured the application to connect to both the queue managers at the same time. The problem is solved now. I will post the updated code in my GitHub repo in a short while. Thank you again for all the help ! Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the Code to connect to multiple queue managers and exchange data between them.
https://github.com/PakaluPap1to/MQ_MultiQueue/tree/master